# How to change angular UI theme to ngx-admin in ABP.io framework

Tags: angular, abp, theming, nebular, ngx-admin

I want to change default ABP.io framework theme to ngx-admin.
I read ABP docs (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Theming) but couldn't figure out how to completely change the UI theme.
I must say that I'm learning ABP.io framework for just a month and I have many things to learn yet. So a detailed guide will be much appreciated.

Comment: did you have any progress?